# How to merge master branch into main

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have created a new remote repo "infrastructure" on GitHub.

I have then created a local repo on my computer in the folder "infr" with `git init`

When I pushed my local repo with `git push -u origin master` the new branch "master" was created.

I want to merge "master" branch into "main" branch now.

After trying to open a pull request git does not detect differences between them and does not let me do the merging, although checking each branch, you can see all files from my project in the master and nothing in the main.

I have tried renaming my "master" branch into "main" but I got an error : "Could not rename branch "master" at this time: New branch already exists".

So how do I merge master into main branch ?

Comment: Did you commit something in your local repo before pushing?

Comment: I created a few files and then I did  `git add .` `git commit -m "message"` and `git push -u origin master`

Comment: Also note that you don't necessarily need to open a PR to merge branches, you can do it locally with Git directly with `git merge master` (when being on `main`), then pushing. For collaborative work, PR are the de facto standard though, before merging.

Comment: After doing `$ git merge main` I got a message `merge: main - not something we can merge` or `git merge master` I got `Already up to date`

Comment: Consider replacing (overwriting) one branch with the other: `git push -f origin master:main` -> push my local branch master into the branch main of origin

Comment: Your state is not very clear. If you want more help, you'll have to show us the commit history of the 2 branches (using `git log --oneline` for instance)

Comment: Take a step back. Do you want "master" or "main" on github? Both git and github are migrating the default branch from "master" to "main" but it depends on the version of the tools you are using which actually is the default branch. Sounds like your git still creates "master" as the default but github (at least the cloud version) has switched. However these are just "default defaults". Unless you want to use main, then the simplet approach is to change the Default Branch under repo Settings>Branches.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I encountered same problem 4 days ago and what I have done is I opened my online repo in git site and went into repo settings and clicked on branches option. I changed the default branch from main to master and i later deleted the main branch as it was empty. tell me if this works for you. [image: github repo settings]

Comment: I tried and I got an error : "Could not rename branch "main" at this time: New branch already exists" https://imgur.com/ey6cxyA

Comment: Dont try to rename.just change default branch from main to master.

Comment: There will be a two way arrow symbol beside pencil icon.

Comment: I had the same problem, it worked for me, thanks for posting, upvoted

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it worked for me and I upvoted your answer, but why would this situation happen in the first place?  is this because git recently decided to use main branch as default. Then should we ideally do git push origin main instead of git push origin master?

Comment: How to delete the unwanted branch ?

Comment: The question is not how to eliminate main but how to merge master into main.

Comment: Many of us still use 'master' on projects. branching is confusing enough without adding 'main' You can add a branch as 'master'. I did that and pushed code I had on a Linux machine. Then cloned using the same repository to my Windows 11 machine. By default of 'main' you may only see a 'read me' file. If you pushed code to 'master' you do set 'master' as default. When you clone it you will get all the code you want.ed.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, I used `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` from main branch and then commit + push which solved the problem in my case.
Found the solution in this [article](https://www.educative.io/answers/the-fatal-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-git-error)

Answer (score 2):

I also got that issue.Try these steps: `git branch main` to create the main branch, `git checkout main` to use the main branch,  then `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated histories`, to pull into the main branch you just created, then `git push --set-upstream origin main` to push from the main branch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The command is ``git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`` Just incase someone tries this solution before the pending edits have been completed. The hyphen was missed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is because you have commit on the main branch (maybe the readme.md) while the master from the local is not clone from the master so it doesn't have the information about the first commit on the main branch. I think you can clone the main branch to a empty local directory and then grab all the files you need from the master directory into that and commit

Answer (score 1):

The following command will add your local project to github.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Comment here"
git remote add origin https://github.com/YourRepoPrefixHere.git
git push -u origin master
```

merge master branch into main

```
git:(master) git branch main
git:(master) git checkout main
git:(main) git pull origin master
git:(main) git checkout master
git:(master) git pull

git pull --rebase
git push --set-upstream origin main
git push -f origin main
```

Answer (score 0):

For future refernce you can follow the following steps shown in the image.[image]

In github go to your repository settings and in the default branch section click the pen icon and a box will pop as shown below where you can make the changes.
[image]

Type the name you want to use for your new branch and click rename branch.