# How do I upload a repository directly to a GitHub Organization?

Tags: git, github

I am unsure whether I've followed this process correctly. I created a project repository on my IDE PyCharm, and tried to upload into a specific GitHub organization that I'm in. On Pycharm, it gives me the option of sharing the code to GitHub. When I do this, it creates a public repository in my gitHub account but not directly in the organization; therefore, I have to clone that one and import it separately in the organization. Is this correct process or is there a way I can import it directly in the organization from my IDE? Do people generally create a repository and then upload/commit files separately from their IDE or am I taking the longer route?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**The easy way to do this using only the GUI/IDE:**

1. Create a project in PyCharm named `your-project`
2. Go to your GitHub organization page and click New and name the repo `your-project` [image]
3. In PyCharm, under the "Git" menu click "Manage Remotes" instead of clicking "GitHub" [image]
4. In the popup, click "+" and add `https://github.com/organization/your-project.git`

The default PyCharm "push" will now upload to your GitHub organization's repo.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround similar to that proposed by @Nathan, though I'm not sure it's the cleanest way (any suggestion to improve is welcome):

1. I created a new repository on github with the same name of my local PyCharm project (let's say it's called `my_pycharm_project`)
2. Following [this guide](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories), from the Terminal inside PyCharm I typed:

`$ git remote add origin https://github.com/organization/my_pycharm_project.git`

3. This works, but then when I push files from local to GitHub inside PyCharm, they are pushed into a `master` branch and not into the `main` branch
4. To overcome this, I then followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68474230/9492673), which basically
   says to: 1) change default branch from main to master (you can do this directly from GitHub) and 2) delete the main branch

Of course it would be cleaner to push to the `main` branch, but I didn't find a way to do this.